# <title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title> getting same in Eclipse using restassured

Tags: eclipse, api, postman, rest-assured

I am getting this error while calling a rest api which is working from postman

IDE : Eclipse and using rest assured

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /serviceurl.postregisterurl. Reason:
<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Any ideas to resolve or debug the issue ?